# RVO vs std::unique_ptr<> cleanup

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value-optimization, object-destruction

This is a question about C++ specs on object destruction vs Return-Value-Optimization.

Can I expect RVO return the right value before `std::unique_ptr<>` cleanup?

```
Foo Bar()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr = new Foo();
    return *ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will return the right value with or without RVO (and there is no RVO in this case). The function returns a concrete `Foo`, so `*ptr` will be *copied* into the return value before destruction of the pointer.

That means,

```
Foo foo;
foo = Bar();
```

is similar to (unwrapping the unique_ptr to be more explicit)

```
  Foo foo;
  Foo* ptr = new Foo;
  foo = *ptr;
finally:
  delete ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

When a function returns a class type object, RVO is allowed under only two circumstances:

- The returned expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object, or
- the returned expression refers to a temporary object which has not been bounded to a reference.

So your code won't trigger RVO.

If the `Foo` object is declared with automatic storage, a compiler is allowed to do RVO:

```
Foo bar()
{
    Foo foo;
    return foo;    // foo can be constructed directly as the returned object
}
```

If for some reason you have to create the object with `new` and want to eliminate the copy operation, you may use `std::move`, which will change an expression into an rvalue:

```
Foo bar()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo);
    return std::move(*ptr);    // No deep copy if Foo implements
                               // its own move constructor
}
```

Comment: @kfmfe04 I don't think `std::move()` is a good idea in this case. According to [Move Semantics and Compiler Optimizations](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_06.html) it makes things worse.

Comment: If you are looking for optimization, (N)RVO is *more* optimal than move constructors.  A move operation into a constructor is still a shallow copy -- it's better than a deep copy but worse than no copy at all.

Comment: @MarkLakata You are right. `std::move` shouldn't be used to return a named automatic object. I have edited my answer.